# Boot-Info Report on Flaky 14.04 on New Dell Inspiron 15-3552

Tags: boot, dell, inspiron

The pre-installed 14.04.5 on this new laptop went flaky after I tried a general software update - it froze part-way through.  I used a 14.04.5 live-USB and the standard method to generate a Boot-Info report which is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23782306/

There is a GNU GRUB "Restore Ubuntu 14.04 to factory state" option which I've not yet tried - hopefully that'll get me back to out-of-the box state which will be fine as I'd done very little with the laptop before trying a global update using Software Updater.

Are there any clues in the report as to why the update failed and trashed the OS?  Was this a one-off?

Comment: Update logs are found in `/var/log/apt`. If you can access this directory using a live USB, check the `history.log` and `term.log` files for clues as to where the update failed.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Appreciate that. I've now removed the laptop's HDD and used Macrium Reflect on my Windows 7 laptop to backup/restore an image to a spare HDD so will take a look at these files later using Windows. The software update froze about 2/3 the way through at "Configuring grub-efi-amd64" (the window greyed-out).

Comment: @OrganicMarble - As it's not easy to examine these files with Windows I used the live-USB and identified sda3 as the partition containing /var, created a mount point and mounted this partition. Nano revealed both history.log and term.log in /var/log/apt were empty. I checked my methodology by backing-up and looking at /var/log/boot.log which contained many entries.

Comment: There may be some older zipped versions named as 'history.log.1.gz` etc. Check the dates to see if they could be relevant.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - There were .gz versions of both. Guess I'll have to unzip before I can open with Nano.